# Does the gamma function depend on lambda?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

In my professor's notes I read the following.

> The gamma-distribution is given by:
>   $$g_a(x)=\frac{\lambda^a}{\Gamma(a)}x^{a-1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x},$$
>
> Where
>
> $$ \Gamma(a) = \int_0^{\infty}\,e^{-x\lambda}\lambda^ax^{a-1}dx \,. $$
>
> Quiz: does the above constant depends on $\lambda$?

How can this integral not depend on $\lambda$? However I read elsewhere that 
 $\int_0^{\infty}\,e^{-x}x^{a-1}dx \,. $ So I am puzzled.

Comment: Change of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the substitution $u = \lambda x$ we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x\lambda} \lambda^a x^{a-1} \, dx
= \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{a-1} \, du.$$

Comment: Wait, if you substitute $\lambda x = u$ wouldn't it be $\lambda^{a-1}$ ?

Comment: @RobertMelikyan Don't forget the extra factor of $\lambda$ when doing the change of variables ($\lambda\, dx = du$).